# How to create mapping with json file in elasticsearch2.3?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I'm using ES2.3

create new index mapping with below command works.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/megacorp' -d '
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 3,
        "number_of_replicas": 1
    }, 
    "mappings": {
        "employee": {
            "properties": {
                "first_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "last_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "age": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }, 
                "about": {
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "interests": {
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "join_time": {
                    "type": "date", 
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime", 
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

now i hope can use a json file to create same index. tmap.json file like below

```
    {
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 3,
        "number_of_replicas": 1
    }, 
    "mappings": {
        "employee": {
            "properties": {
                "first_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "last_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "age": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }, 
                "about": {
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "interests": {
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "join_time": {
                    "type": "date", 
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime", 
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aliases": [ "source" ]
  }
```

then i usr curl to create it.

```
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/megacorp' --data-binary @tmap.json
```

and

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/megacorp' -d @tmap.json
```

both above commands not working, get error like below.

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"class_cast_exception","reason":"java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map"}],"type":"class_cast_exception","reason":"java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map"},"status":500}%
```

how to create index with curl and my json file? this is really confused me for long time.

can any body help me? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way you define alias is wrong. It should be a map instead of an array.

```
  {
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 3,
        "number_of_replicas": 1
    }, 
    "mappings": {
        "employee": {
            "properties": {
                "first_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "last_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "age": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }, 
                "about": {
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "interests": {
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "join_time": {
                    "type": "date", 
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime", 
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aliases": { "source": {} }
  }
```

More info about aliases in index creation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#create-index-aliases

Comment: i got it, thanks. other question, how to storage template file in config/templates folder, do you know it?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you mean by template file? I don't think Elasticsearch has something called template file.

Comment: thanks for your help. I found it from ES version 2.0 or newer will not supported for template files storage in local file, you have to use curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/xxx -d '{}' for your template. other will would be possible you storage it on local folder then run command by handle , like curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/xxx -d @templatefile